# Unnesting multiple tibbles inside a tibble to split Mutli-Select survey questions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, survey

I'm trying to generate a programmatic solution for expanding 'Multiple Response' questions from surveys into separate columns. The set-up involves survey data (df1) and a helper file that relates the variables to information about the variable. With the sample data below the goal is to expand the responses in DVar and EVar into separate columns, e.g. DVar.A, DVar.b, etc..., with binary 1,0 whether that ID checked the appropriate box.

```
df1 <- tibble(ID = rep(1:8), AVar = sample(1:10, 8), BVar = rnorm(8), 
              CVar = c("Got", "Some", "Stuff", "In", "Here", "Got", "Others", "Too"),
              DVar = c("A,B", NA , "C", "A,C", "B,D", "C", "D", "B,D"), 
              EVar = c("Banana,Apple", "Orange,Raspberry", "Apple", NA, "Orange", "Banana", "Banana", "Raspberry"))

Helper <- tibble(VariableName = c("ID", "AVar", "BVar", "CVar", "DVar", "EVar"), 
                 QuestionType = c("ID", "Numeric", "Numeric", "Single Response", "Multiple Response", "Multiple Response"))
```

The current working function takes in an ID and the column to spread. For my current purposes, this function works great. Except when a column has an absence of NAs (which is unusual), which throws an error about 'None' not in the dataset on the final select statement.

```
MultiToCol <- function(ID, toSpread) {
  X <- tibble(ID, toSpread)
  
  X %>% mutate(varLong = strsplit(as.character(replace_na(toSpread, "None")),split=",")) %>% 
    unnest(varLong) %>% mutate(tmpValue = 1) %>% spread(varLong, tmpValue, fill = 0) %>% select(-None, -ID, -toSpread, None)
  
}
```

Using mutate(across) I am able to get the necessary data back, which is then joined back to the full data set (or could be in the example).

```
getCols <- Helper %>% filter(QuestionType == "Multiple Response") %>% select(VariableName)

spreadCols <- df1 %>% select_if(names(.) %in% c('ID', getCols$VariableName)) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = !ID, .fns = ~MultiToCol1(ID,.)))
```

When I View the data, rstudio gives me what I want back out!

```
ID  DVar.A  DVar.B  DVar.C  DVar.D  DVar.None   EVar.Apple  EVar.Banana EVar.Orange EVar.Raspberry  Evar.None
1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
⋮
```

However, when writing the data, I receive an error about mismatched dimensions. This is because the resulting data structure is an 8x3 tibble with columns that are (Int, Tibble, Tibble). And the internal Tibbles seem to be transposed.

```
tibble [8 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ID  : int [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ DVar: tibble [8 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ A   : num [1:8] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  ..$ B   : num [1:8] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
  ..$ C   : num [1:8] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
  ..$ D   : num [1:8] 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
  ..$ None: num [1:8] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ EVar: tibble [8 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ Apple    : num [1:8] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ..$ Banana   : num [1:8] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
  ..$ Orange   : num [1:8] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
  ..$ Raspberry: num [1:8] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
  ..$ None     : num [1:8] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Using the *unnest* function yields the same error as the *write_* functions about mismatched dimensions.

I've also attempted to use *unnest_wider*, but am running into issues with multiple tibble-columns as *unnest_wider* function only takes a single column as an argument.

I've tried to use *pivot_wider* but cannot figure out how to pass it the column names correctly from  getCols$VariableName.

I have some of my failed attempts that I can add, but I kinda feel this is a simple solution with map, and I'm just not hitting on it.

Are there any simple solutions to unnest multiple tibbles from inside a tibble. Happy to hear any other feedback to create a tidier, more elegant solution for the larger problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    select_if(names(.) %in% c('ID', getCols$VariableName)) %>%
    cSplit_e("DVar", type = "character", fill = 0, sep=",") %>% 
    cSplit_e("EVar", type = "character", fill = 0, sep=",")
```

Or if we wanted to use for multiple columns, an option is `map`

```
library(purrr)
tmp <- df1 %>%  
           select_if(names(.) %in% c('ID', getCols$VariableName))
map_dfc(setdiff(names(tmp), "ID"), ~
     tmp %>%
      select(.x) %>% 
      cSplit_e( .x, type = "character", fill = 0, sep=",") %>% 
      select(-.x)) %>% 
 bind_cols(tmp, .)
```

---

Using the OP's function, it can be easily flattened with `as.data.frame`

```
out <- df1 %>%
    select_if(names(.) %in% c('ID', getCols$VariableName)) %>% 
    mutate(across(.cols = !ID, .fns = ~MultiToCol(ID,.))) %>% 
    do.call(data.frame, .)
out
  ID DVar.A DVar.B DVar.C DVar.D DVar.None EVar.Apple EVar.Banana EVar.Orange EVar.Raspberry EVar.None
1  1      1      1      0      0         0          1           1           0              0         0
2  2      0      0      0      0         1          0           0           1              1         0
3  3      0      0      1      0         0          1           0           0              0         0
4  4      1      0      1      0         0          0           0           0              0         1
5  5      0      1      0      1         0          0           0           1              0         0
6  6      0      0      1      0         0          0           1           0              0         0
7  7      0      0      0      1         0          0           1           0              0         0
8  8      0      1      0      1         0          0           0           0              1         0



str(out)
#'data.frame':  8 obs. of  11 variables:
# $ ID            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
# $ DVar.A        : num  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
# $ DVar.B        : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
# $ DVar.C        : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
# $ DVar.D        : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
# $ DVar.None     : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ EVar.Apple    : num  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
# $ EVar.Banana   : num  1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
# $ EVar.Orange   : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
# $ EVar.Raspberry: num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
# $ EVar.None     : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or can use `invoke`

```
 ....
   %>% invoke(data.frame, .)
```

Comment: Using data.frame works great. It really is that simple! I am interested in the 'splitstackshape' solution. I hadn't seen this package yet.

Comment: Using 'data.frame' works great. It really is that simple! I am still interested in the slipstackshape solution. The first example wouldn't work as it uses the variable names DVar and eVar. Since this will be a functional solution, it needs to pass the column names from the HelperFile (getCols). I would like to figure out how to use mutate(across. But how do you send BOTH the data and the column(s) as arguments to the functions? Since the dot now represents the column.

Comment: @DizzorTwizzle You can loop over the names of the dataset and pass it in `cSplit_e` i..e `tmp <- df1 %>%
    select_if(names(.) %in% c('ID', getCols$VariableName)); map_dfc(setdiff(names(tmp), "ID"), ~ tmp %>% select(.x) %>% cSplit_e( .x, type = "character", fill = 0, sep=",") %>% bind_cols(tmp, .)`

Comment: That does the trick!! Thanks again for the magic @akrun (and all the other solutions I've used over the years)!   Only made one minor change to column bind to clean-up the output. ```bind_cols(ID=tmp$ID,.)```